How can I display the execution progress of Artisan commands in a web page?
In the terminal, there are progress bar for long running tasks. How can i implement same effect on the web page.
I would like the artisan command to work when I click the button on the web page. There will be a progress bar showing long running tasks progress. When it is complete, the progress bar will reach 100% and refresh the page.

you web request would eventually timeout, while console commands are made to run for a long time. Why do you want to mix the two?

Step 1: Set Up Laravel Artisan Command
First, you need a long-running Artisan command in Laravel. Here’s a simple example:
app/Console/Commands/LongRunningTask.php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class LongRunningTask extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'task:long-running';

    protected $description = 'Perform a long-running task';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        $totalSteps = 100;
        for ($i = 0; $i <= $totalSteps; $i++) {
            // Simulate long task
            sleep(1);

            // Update progress
            $this->info($i);
        }
    }
 }

Step 2: Create a Route and Controller
//routes/web.php

use App\Http\Controllers\TaskController;

Route::get('/start-task', [TaskController::class, 'startTask']);

// app/Http/Controllers/TaskController.php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;

class TaskController extends Controller
{
    public function startTask()
    {
        $process = new Process(['php', 'artisan', 'task:long-running']);
        $process->start();
        return response()->json(['status' => 'started']);
    }
}

Step 3: Set Up the Frontend
Create a simple HTML page with a button to start the task and a progress bar:
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Progress Bar Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="startTaskButton">Start Task</button>
    <div id="progressContainer" style="display:none;">
        <div id="progressBar" style="width: 0%; height: 30px; background: green;"></div>
    </div>

    <script>
        document.getElementById('startTaskButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
            fetch('/start-task')
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    if (data.status === 'started') {
                        document.getElementById('progressContainer').style.display = 'block';
                        updateProgress();
                    }
                });
        });

        function updateProgress() {
            let progress = 0;
            let interval = setInterval(() => {
                progress++;
                document.getElementById('progressBar').style.width = progress + '%';
                
                if (progress >= 100) {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    setTimeout(() => location.reload(), 1000);
                }
            }, 1000); // Assuming the task takes 100 seconds, adjust accordingly
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>

Step 4: Update the Backend to Handle Progress
To handle real-time progress updates, you would typically use WebSockets or a similar real-time communication method. However, for simplicity, we simulate the progress with a fixed interval.
To implement real-time updates using WebSockets, you can use Laravel Echo and Pusher or a similar service. Here’s a simplified version:
Install Laravel Echo and Pusher.
Broadcast progress updates from the command.
Listen for updates on the frontend and update the progress bar accordingly.
This simple example should give you a basic understanding of how to implement a progress bar for long-running tasks initiated from a web page. For a more robust solution, consider implementing real-time updates using WebSockets.
